# HADOOP - Permission denied executing ./start-yarn.sh Ubuntu 18

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-18.04

I am installing Hadoop in Ubuntu 18.04 following [this tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-on-ubuntu/). I have tried to solve it reading stackoverflow answers, but I am still having the issue. Here is the output. What can I do?

```
hadoop@victor-GL552VW:~/hadoop/sbin$ ./start-yarn.sh
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: hadoop@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: You need to enable passwordless SSH... If you can't do `ssh hadoop@localhost`, then the scripts don't work

Comment: I can do ssh hadoop@localhost, but not execute ./start-yarn.sh

Comment: If you're able to do that without it asking for a password, then I'm not sure why you'd be getting permission denied. The error says that the key or the password is denied. If it has no password, then that implies the key would need regenerated / added to the authorized keys file